# Cron expression: Run weekly on Tuesdays and Wednesdays starting NOW

Tags: java, spring, cron

I need some help from people with Cron knowledge. I'm trying to write Cron expression which should run weekly once on Tuesday and once on Wednesday starting immediately if it is Tuesday today. My current solution is:

`0 0 * * 2,3`

This expression runs Cron at 00:00 on Tuesdays and Wednesdays. 
But it will not run if it is Tuesday today, because time is already ahead 00:00. If I set time to current hour and minute, let say 16:30, then Cron will start now on Tuesday, but then Wednesday will start at 16:30 as well. I want to start all next Сron events as soon as possible, i.e. on Wednesday's at 00:00

Is it possible to solve this task at all? Many thanks for any effort to help.

Comment: I've never heard of cron being able to do anything like this, and I'm an old timer.  Why not just run your job once if it's Tuesday or Wednesday?  If you're creating this cron task manually, you can just do that manually.  If you're putting the creation of the cron task in a script, have your script also check if it should run the job once right away.

Comment: @Joe Admin, thanks for your comment. Do you mean that I need to create 2 cron jobs, one for Tuesday and one for Wednesday? Could you, assist me on doing it? Please, provide your way of implementation as an answer.

Comment: You have to run the cron every minute, but the cron does not only run the `command` but it first checks if it already ran on that day. You can do this by touching a file and compare the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem that you want to run a job on every TUE and WED 's mid-night, and also want to run immediately when the application start at TUE or WED. Not aware and never heard cron expression can handle that "start immediately" behaviour. But you can use simply use `@PostConstruct` to achieve it :

```
public class CronJob {

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStart() {
       LocalDateTime now =LocalDateTime.now();
       if(now.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY || now.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY  ) {
            if(!now.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) {
                 doJob();
            }
        }

    }

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * 2,3")
    public void onSchedule() {
         doJob();
    }

    public void doJob(){
        //do the job
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a tripple cron of the following type:

```
* * * * 2 [ ! -e "$HOME/cronflag2" ] && touch "$HOME/cronflag2" && command 
* * * * 3 [ ! -e "$HOME/cronflag3" ] && touch "$HOME/cronflag3" && command
0 0 * * 4 rm "$HOME/cronflag2" "$HOME/cronflag3"
```

The first command will only execute if a flag-file is not available. If it is not available it will make it and execute the command.